# Counting semaphore that supports multiple acquires in an atomic call - how would this be implemented in terms of other primitives?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, language-agnostic, semaphore

Suppose that I have many tasks to run that each will consume a known amount of some finite resource (say, memory or disk space) while they are running. Each task will fit within the available resource constraints individually, but there is not enough available to run everything simultaneously. My goal is to allow tasks to "claim" the resources that they will need, or wait until those resources are available. I don't care about optimizing what order the tasks run in (so, for example, first-come first-served would be fine), but the solution must not deadlock and should meet a reasonable notion of "as concurrent as possible" (so "just do tasks one at a time", while technically correct, is not a solution).

I'm imagining a synchronization object somewhat like a semaphore, but instead of acquiring a single permit from a fixed-size pool, each task acquires a "slice" of the appropriate size. While some programming languages appear to offer this functionality (for example, [Java's Semaphore supports it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire-int-)), it doesn't seem common, and it's not clear if these implementations can deadlock or not. It's possible that I'm just missing the right search term, though.

A naive approach would be to use a counting semaphore with a large initial value (say, 1 per MiB of memory available), and for each task to acquire permits from the semaphore repeatedly - so a task needing 10 MiB of memory would acquire ten permits. However, this is prone to deadlock - tasks could be blocked partway through acquiring their permits, preventing other smaller tasks from running.

Is there a name for this synchronization object? How could it be safely implemented in terms of more common primitives such as locks, condition variables, and (ordinary) counting semaphores?

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using a condition variable (CV) and a private counter, as long as the CV supports notifying all waiting tasks. You can use the CV to provide exclusive access to the counter, and to notify threads to re-check the counter if they're waiting for it to be large enough.

To initialize, set the private counter to the initial value of the multi-acquire semaphore. To implement `acquire(count)`, use the CV to wait for the counter to be at least `count`, decrement the counter by `count`, and return. To implement `release(count)`, acquire the CV, increment the counter by `count`, and notify all listeners on the CV so that the waiting tasks can re-check the value of the counter.

An example of this approach in Python:

```py
from asyncio import Condition

class Mlemaphore:
    """Like a Semaphore, but with atomic acquire(count). Not thread-safe.

    Has a silly name until someone tells me what these are supposed to be called."""

    def __init__(self, value: int = 1):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Mlemaphore initial value must be >= 0")
        self._counter = value
        self._condition = Condition()
        pass

    async def acquire(self, count: int = 1) -> None:
        """Acquire count permits atomically, or wait until they are available."""

        async with self._condition:
            await self._condition.wait_for(lambda: self._counter >= count)
            self._counter -= count

    def locked(self, count: int = 1) -> bool:
        """Return True if acquire(count) would not return immediately."""

        return self._counter < count

    async def release(self, count: int = 1) -> None:
        """Release count permits.

        Note that unlike in Semaphore, this method is async."""

        async with self._condition:
            self._counter += count
            self._condition.notify_all()
```

Note: the warning about thread-safety is because Python has both "asyncio", which is a single-threaded approach to concurrency using an event loop, and threading. This sample code is based on the asyncio CV primitive, and thus is asyncio-safe but not thread-safe. Building the exact same logic out of a thread-safe CV (in Python or any other language) would result in a thread-safe Mlemaphore.